# How I can calculate big numbers in python

Tags: python

I am looking for calculating big numbers on python
but it can not .

like this:

9999999999999999999999999999999999**999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999

Comment: You know that the result of your computation is a number with 10^52 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `DecInt` module.
Can be found [here](http://home.comcast.net/~casevh/)

```
import DecInt
bignum = DecInt.DecInt(9999999999999999) ** 999999999999999999999
print str(bignum)
```

Comment: Added a small example, hope it helps.

Comment: @OfirFarchy: you haven't tried your example, right?

Comment: @thg435 I have, just not with these numbers... I assume it takes a while ;) and I think the limit is a 200k digit result.

Answer (score 8):

Python supports long-integers so you can just print the expression. It probably isn't as efficient as GMP or other libraries but the problem with what you want to do is that it is not possible to compute that value:

`(10**35 - 1) ** (10**52 - 1)` is approximately `10 ** (35 * 10**52)` which contains about `10**52` digits.

Let us consider how big a memory chip we could hypothetically manifacture. The mass of the Moon is about `7.34767309 * 10^22` kg and the mass of an electron is `9.10938188 * 10^(-31)` kg.
Let us suppose we can use an electron to save a decimal digit. This means that using the Moon as memory we could use about `8.066050130286116 * 10^52` electrons.

What does this mean? That if you had a super RAM chip as big as the Moon you'll be able to compute that number. If you got it , well good for you, otherwise if you are a mortal you simply can not hope to have enough memory.

The `DecInt` module can help you with numbers with 100k-some millions of digit, but more than that you need specific hardware and with even bigger numbers(as the example you showed) is simply not possible.

Comment: Yes, was about to say the same. Assume they manage to _compute_ that number. How long would it take to _print_ it?

Comment: Well, if they manage to compute it then the time taken to print it would be negligible(since you are just adding an O(n) step to a computation that has much worse complexity). Nevertheless it would take probably more than the current age of the universe I think.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer I've edited.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you make number as string
and make function which do similar things as human's hand, multiplying with string.

assume you make 2 string
"99876" and
"123"

and make str_multiply function
which takes 2 argument as parameter

get string length of latter.
"123" made up of 3 character so it is 3(ignore null character)
here is pseudo code

```
len_2 = string_len(latter);
len_1 = string_len(former);
flag = 0;
result_string = "";
for(i=len_2-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    for(k=len_1;k>=0;k--)
    {
        a = alphabet_to_integer(latter[i]);
        b = alphabet_to_integer(former[k]);
        c = a*b;
        c = c * 10 + flag;

        flag = c/10;
        ch = integer_to_alphabet(c%10);
        result_string = concat(ch,result_string);
    }
}
```

if you want to not just 2 number but 10 number(or more)
you can just call str_multiply function again and again.

it is first time I answer to someone else's question.
so I hope this help more than usual 
thanks!